# any free utility to create deeply nested blank folders quickly

Tags: windows-xp

any free utility to create deeply nested blank folders quickly.

Quickly make multiple subfolders within a folder.

Comment: On what criteria ? Simply creating one subfolder within another or ... ? Also, what is a blank folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A free little gui tool that can make a deep set of folders from a text file defining them is here:
http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=17416.0

If that doesn't do what you want, post a request on the forum coding snacks section, and someone will code up a little freeware tool for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The mkdir command-line utility can do this:

```
C:\>mkdir a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l
```

explanation from `mkdir /?`:

```
MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
For example, assume \a does not exist then:

    mkdir \a\b\c\d

is the same as:

    mkdir \a
    chdir \a
    mkdir b
    chdir b
    mkdir c
    chdir c
    mkdir d
```

Comment: how to create subfolder along with folder in 3 -4level deep. with custom name

Comment: i found this commercial need freeware like this http://www.skyjuicesoftware.com/software/fmk_info.html

Comment: like `mkdir folder1\folder2\custom_folder` ?

Comment: is there any gui for mkdir?

Comment: Do you really need a GUI for something that simple?

Comment: there are some shareware programs (e.g. Batch Folder Creator, Folder Maker Pro ... holy sh*t, the art to create a directory like a PROfessional) with a GUI. the programmers assume correctly that someone who needs a GUI to create a folder would be silly enough to pay for it :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's multiple folders within the one folder you might want to investigate [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx). This will allow you to create a script to loop creating folders.